# Why temporal lobe is called temporal?

Tags: brain

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_lobe

Does this have something to do with tempo (time?)

Temporal lobe is behind (posterior) to frontal lobe, inferior to parietal lobe and is in front of occipital lobe.

Why it's called temporal?

Answer (score 13):

The temporal lobe is in the temporal region of the head, near the temples of the skull, hence the name. It's name does not relate to it's biological function, it is mainly involved in processing language, visual memories, and emotions. The medulla oblongata is one region of the brain that deals with a lot of the "tempo" type functions (tempo as in keeping rhythm) such as controlling the heart beat and breathing rate.

> [Temple indicates the side of the head behind the eyes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_%28anatomy%29)

Comment: The different etymologies of temporal can be found on this [wiki article](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temporal)

Comment: yes, temporal in this sense has a different etymological root to tempo.

Comment: is temporal means sideways?